# System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<DateTime> is executed for nullable DateTime properties as well

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

So, basically I wanted to create a custom converter in order to convert datetime values according to user timezone. Here is the code:

```
public class UserBasedDateTimeJsonConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public UserBasedDateTimeJsonConverter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeof(DateTime) == typeToConvert;
    }

    public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TryGetDateTime(out var date))
        {
            return date;
        }

        throw new Exception("Error");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null)
        {
            var securityContextProvider = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ISecurityContextProvider>();

            var securityContext = securityContextProvider.SecurityContext;

            if (securityContext.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteStringValue(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(value, securityContext.UserToken.TimeZoneInfo));
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    var logger = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<UserBasedDateTimeJsonConverter>>();
                    logger.LogInformation(e, e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}

public class CustomJsonOptions : IConfigureOptions<JsonOptions>
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;

    public FeatureConfigJsonOptions(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public void Configure(JsonOptions options)
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new UserBasedDateTimeJsonConverter(_accessor));
    }
}
```

It works fine but the only odd thing is that when I have a custom model which contains a nullable DateTime value, the converter -> read method will hit as well. And, of course for nullable types I dont know what to return.

Why would this converter try to read the data if the property is nullable DateTime ?

EDIT:

Add some more info:

Basically my request model is:

```
public class NewApplicationKeyRequest
{
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime? Expired { get; set; }
}
```

But when I do the request the `CanConvert` is hit 5 times:

1. For `NewApplicationKeyRequest`
2. For `Guid`  -> `ApplicationId`
3. For `string` -> `Description`
4. For `DateTime?` -> `Expired`
5. For `DateTime` -> No idea why this is somehow created under the hood by Asp.Net core. Maybe is some sort of backing field for the `Expired`. And this is the one causing the problem.

Comment: @Llama Read method does not return nullable type

Comment: And the value (in `Expired` field) is null or not, when it's being called?

Comment: @Evk it is null

Comment: @Rey did you get any solution ?

Comment: @Ajith I have provided the solution in the comment.

Comment: @Rey Sorry, I can't see any solution from the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding also a `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<DateTime?>` class it seems that the non-nullable version was not hit anymore.